# dimension called "time" exists, but variable "time" uses a different dimension

Tags: netcdf, nco

How can one give this peculiar netCDF file a proper time axis?

"time" exists as both a dimension and a variable, 
but the time *variable* uses "serial\ date\ number" as its *dimension*.

There are two challenges: 
1. the variables vs. dimensions issue; and 
2. "serial\ date\ number" appears to indicate spaces (with backslash delimiters) on some systems, but has underscores ("serial_date_number") on other systems.

```
netcdf 
dimensions:
 lon = 80 ;
 lat = 41 ;
 pres = 27 ;
 time = 12053 ;
 serial\ date\ number = 12053 ;
variables:
 double u_mjo(time, pres, lat, lon) ;
 double lon(lon) ;
 lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
 double lat(lat) ;
 lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
 double p_level(pres) ;
 p_level:units = "hPa" ;
 double time(serial\ date\ number) ;
 time:units = "days since 0000-01-01 00:00 UTC" ;
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the procedure that worked for me **using only NCO commands** (no ncdump/manual edit/ncgen step):

Extract 4 time steps from OPeNDAP dataset to local netCDF file `allfields.nc`:

```
   ncks -d time,0,3 -d serial_date_number,0,3
    http://weather.rsmas.miami.edu/repository/opendap/synth:100ae90b-71ac-4d38-add9-f8982a976322:L2FsbGZpZWxkcy5uYw==/entry
    -O allfields.nc
```

Extract the `time` variable into a separate file `time.nc`:

```
ncks -v time allfields.nc time.nc
```

Extract everything *except* the `time` variable to a separate file `fixed.nc` (which also  removes the problematic `serial_date_number` dimension`):

```
ncks -C -x -v time allfields.nc fixed.nc
```

Rename the dimension `serial_data_number` to `time`:

```
ncrename -O -d serial_date_number,time time.nc
```

Append the file with fixed time to the file without time:

```
ncks -A time.nc fixed.nc
```

The files I used and created in this workflow may be seen here:
http://geoport.whoi.edu/thredds/catalog/usgs/data2/rsignell/models/mapes/catalog.html

Comment: Yep. Well done. Can't think of a more elegant solution than Rich's. Not sure what's going on with the underscores. I assume that simply renaming the dimension "serial_date_number" to "time" fails because of "String match to name in use". That would be more elegant if it worked, but the netCDF library prevents it. Not sure why renaming to an existing dimension of the same size must fail, but it does. cz

Answer (score 0):

The solution to convert original.nc to fixed.nc, addressing the 2 challenges,  was (after much wrangling) this:

```
# 1. extract time from the original.nc file to create a new file with only time:
 ncks -v time original.nc time.nc

# 2. remove the time variable from original.nc (which removes the problematic `serial_date_number dimension`)
 ncks -C -x -v time original.nc fixed.nc

#3. Fix the time.nc file manually, with a text editor:
 ncdump time.nc > time.txt   # dump netCDF to text
    ## text-edit time.txt to fix up header, 
    ## creating time = UNLIMITED ; // (12053 currently)
 ncgen -o newtime.nc < time.txt   # remake netCDF from text

# 4. Finally, concatenate the new time variable file into fixed.nc
 ncks -A newtime.nc fixed.nc
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 I was able to do:

```
ncrename -v variable\ with\ whitespace,variable_with_whitespace filein.nc fileout.nc
```

Comment: Sure, but can you be a bit more specific?